# Parse.com Cloud Code: OutOfMemoryError when rendering big JSON

Tags: parse-platform

I'm using Parse.com's hosting service as a testing server. I got OutOfMemoryError when I requested test data from Parse.com.

My source code is below (part of app.js). Each file is 1.5 Mbyte JSON file. Are there any ways to fix it?

If I use smaller file like 20Kbyte, downloading is no problem.

Thanks,

```
[app.js]

app.get('/sample.php', auth, function(req, res) {

  if (req.query.index == 0) {
    res.render('sample_0', {});
  } else if (req.query.index == 1) {
    res.render('sample_1', {});
  } else if (req.query.index == 2) {
    res.render('sample_2', {});
  } else if (req.query.index == 3) {
    res.render('sample_3', {});
  } else {
    res.json([]);
  }

});
```

Comment: What is reporting an OutOfMemoryError? Which JavaScript function, or is Parse.com giving the error?

Comment: @Ken Y-N Thanks for you comment. I'm using the parse.com's cloud code.

Comment: You say "app.js is here", but where is "here"?